# C dynamically include library, by copying raw function data to memory block

Tags: c, function, dll, function-pointers

I thought if I have the raw machine code output of an individual function, that I could read it with dread into an block of memory, and just create an function pointer to there, to dynamically include a function at runtime.

Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would work, but not in a cross-platform way. Memory returned by `malloc` is not executable, at least it is not guaranteed to be. On Windows you'll have to use `VirtualAlloc`, followed by `VirtualProtect` with the `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` flag. On Linux, look into `mprotect`. There can also be differences based on compiler used and machine architecture, for a Linux+GCC example see this [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/the-repetitive-byte-counter/160236#160236).

Though why not just dynamically load the shared library with `LoadLibrary`+`GetProcAddress` (Win) or `dlopen`+`dlsym` (Linux)?